# Верно ли найдены все грамматические основы в предложении:

Tags: основа, предикатив

"И лучших дней надежды и любовь в груди моей – все оживает вновь, и мысли далеко несутся, и полон ум желаний и страстей, и кровь кипит, и слезы из очей, как звуки, друг за другом льются,"?

Собственный вариант: 1. надежды и любовь всё оживает вновь 2. мысли далеко несутся 3. полон ум 4. кровь кипит 5. слёзы льются

Всё верно или есть ошибки?

Comment: Вы найдите, а мы, если нужно, исправим! Форум не выполняет домашних заданий.

Comment: Извините, я не поняла этого.
Тогда вот:
1. надежды и любовь всё оживает вновь
2. мысли далеко несутся
3. полон ум
4. кровь кипит
5. слёзы льются

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И лучших дней **надежды и любовь** в груди моей – **все оживает** вновь, и **мысли** далеко **несутся**, и **полон ум** желаний и страстей, и **кровь кипит**, и **слезы** из очей, как звуки, друг за другом **льются**,"?

Это ССП с союзной связью предложений, в первом предложении подлежащее выражено однородным рядом  и обобщающим словом.

Comment: Вера,честно говоря,я не очень понял: дней чего или что? Т.е. здесь надежда во.ч. или род.пад.?

Comment: Я так поняла: надежды (какие? лучших дней ) или надежды (чего? лучших дней) - здесь "лучших дней" - определение или дополнение, от этого смысл зависит (автор или говорит о прошлом, или надеется на будущее?).

Comment: Да, скорее, Вы правы. Я просто подумал, что ***надежды*** здесь определение.